# Is it possible to override a function of js.html.Window class in Haxe?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, overriding, haxe

I'm trying to **port** some code from **JS** to **Haxe**.

The code overrides Window.getComputedStyle to workarround a firefox issue ([Bugzilla link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548397)):

```
   window.oldGetComputedStyle = window .getComputedStyle;
   window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
      var t = window.oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
      if (t === null) {
         return {};
      } else{
         return t;
      }
   };
```

How can I solve this?

When I tried, I got the following error:

```
Cannot rebind this method : please use 'dynamic' before method declaration
```

Comment: The question you are asking needs clarification. The answer to "Can I override this function using Haxe?" is yes or no. Changing your question to ask for clarification on your error will help you get better information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.
I needed to assign the `Window` as `untyped` to bypass the compiler errors:

```
iframe = cast Browser.document.getElementById("iframe");
var window = untyped iframe.contentWindow;
var oldGetComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle;
window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
    var t = oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
    if (t == null) {
        return {};
    } else{
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get away with only prefixing with `untyped` the _necessary_ assignment: `untyped window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) { ...`.  This is a bit better, because it limits a lot the scope of the untyped and unsafe block (and you `window` variable can remain typed).  For a full example, check [this](http://try.haxe.org/#164F3) _Try Haxe_ link.

Comment: Good advise, and thank you for the _Try Haxe_ link! very useful!